# How can I make Strawberry Perl's cpan(1) find perl?

Tags: perl, makefile, cpan, strawberry-perl

I'm having trouble installing Template module with Strawberry Perl.

```
cpan Template
```

yields the following:

```
 Writing Makefile for AppConfig
 C:strawberryperlbinperl.exe: not found
 dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'`
```

I haven't been able to understand either

- how to affect the path so `dmake` will work correctly
- why the path (which is correct) does not have any \ in it.

Comment: Can you install any other modules? Say something simple like Tie::Cycle?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear that I can install any other modules.

Comment: Did you perhaps install Strawberry Perl into a path with a space in it like `C:\Strawberry Perl`?

Comment: AppConfig isn't doing anything funny so it might be a MakeMaker problem.  The simplest way to handle this is for you to run `cpan`, do `look AppConfig` which will put you into a shell inside the AppConfig build directory, run the Makefile.PL and send the complete Makefile to `bugs-ExtUtils-MakeMaker@rt.cpan.org` along with what version of Strawberry you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've been using MKS, you not only need to be sure you've removed it from your PATH, but you also need to ensure you don't have SHELL set to point to the MKS sh.exe.

I removed it from my PATH, and continued to struggle with this for a couple of more days until I realized dmake was invoking the wrong shell.

Hope this helps someone else down the road.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for this. An MKS install totally broke my perl setup - thought I'd got over all of the associated issues but here's another!

Comment: Almost a year later and this has solved my problem again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer was I needed to uninstall (or at least remove from my path) the MKSTookit (basically a unix shell environment for Windows like Cygwin.) Not exactly sure why this fixed the problem - but it has cleared things up and I am able to install via CPAN.
Thanks for everybody's answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably been bit by escaping. Somewhere something is configured with the path `C:\strawberryperl\bin\perl.exe`, but those slashes need to be escaped to:

`C:\\strawberryperl\\bin\\perl.exe`

Not knowing more about how you installed your perl, I can't tell you where this bad config value is likely to be found.

Comment: C:\\strawberryperl\\bin\\perl.exe is how it appears in my Config.pl file.

Comment: What does it look like in the Makefile (it will be the PERL or FULLPERL variable), what version of MakeMaker was the Makefile generated with (it will say so at the top), and what version of Strawberry is this?